# Generate a set of abstract search terms

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data

I am developing an application for research purposes that uses randomly generated tweets to detect emerging conceptual topics. I need to collect a large amount of them (let's say, beyond 5 million) and due to the fact that I want the application to detect all kinds of topics, I need to generate a **set of the most general or abstract search terms** I can find in order to query the stream. The problem is that I can't figure out how or where should I search for these search terms. Let's put it that way: if you had a dataset which consisted of the entire knowledge of the human population and you want to generate a representative subset of it, with which search terms would you query this dataset?
Is it going to be something like this:

```
Technology,
People,
Politics,
...
```

Is there a set of the most abstract concepts which I can study?

P.S.: Of course I know that Twitter hasn't got the entire knowledge of humans, but you get the picture ;)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should look up "(hierarchical) topic modeling" and "ontology/taxonomy induction"; see for example [Topic Models for Taxonomies](http://dirichlet.net/pdf/bakalov12topic.pdf).